# Healing vial used by Batman

Tags: dc, comics, the-batman

Near the end of the movie **The Batman** and while fighting with some villains.

> Batman gets seriously injured and loses his ability to continue fighting, he reaches for a small vial of green liquid out of his utility belt and inject it. This green liquid heals Batman almost instantaneously in order to finish the battle for Gotham.

It is not addressed in the movie, but what do we know from comics about it?

Comment: Sounds like Venom or Lazarus pit.

Comment: "Green liquid" and "healing" does sound a lot like DC Comics' lazarus pit.

Comment: But Lazarus pit does not sound a lot like *the Batman* movie (very realistic, early stage of the Bat's career)

Comment: My assumption would simply be [drugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_psychoactive_drugs_used_by_militaries) as have been used by the military before, a combination of stimulants and painkillers to allow the subject to keep fighting without acknowledging the injury (which, of course, means they're likely to be even more injured afterwards).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the screenplay](https://deadline.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/The-Batman-Read-The-Screenplay.pdf) (scene 177), it's adrenaline

> BATMAN FIGHTS TO GET UP -- HE CAN'T -- AS SELINA
> STRUGGLES -- HE FUMBLES SOMETHING FROM HIS BELT -- AN
> AUTO-INJECTOR: ADRENALINE -- HE JAMS IT INTO HIS NECK!

Answer (score 5):

For all we can tell, it could simply be a powerful [Adrenaline Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjD2f.jpg) with a different color. Because at this point:

- Lazarus Pit is not introduced, and at this stage, batman wouldn't be that much comfortable using it.
- Bane or venom isn't introduced, so until further reveals, it's unlikely

That being said, we don't yet know the full rogues' gallery this batman has, so venom is still a possibility.

Rogues' gallery as seen in The Batman:

> Riddler, Joker, Penguin

Comment: Given that the world in the batman have no fantastic at all at the moment (except musquito bullets), and the global reaction of batman, it seems pretty obvious it's adrenaline.